# pip unable to install any package and terminal broken

Tags: python, linux, pip, easy-install

I tried to install a python package "BeautifulSoup" and it gave a error message: "pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound". After going through stackoverflow website I download a python script and ran it:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/oodt/tools/oodtsite.publisher/trunk/distribute_setup.py

Now it is throwing a new error message when I try to install `sudo pip install beautifulsoup4`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
  from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 45
  def _bypass_ensure_directory(name, mode=0777):
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Another interesting thing is when a type a wrong command in terminal like "lss" or anything error message is like this appear:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 8, in <module>
  import CommandNotFound
File "/usr/share/command-not-found/CommandNotFound/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
File "/usr/share/command-not-found/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 13
  except gdbm.error, err:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could someone guide me in how to resolve this? My system:

- kernel: 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64 (64 bit)
- desktop: MATE 1.10.0
- distro: LinuxMint 2 betsy

**Solution**

Changed the symblic link "python" in /usr/bin to point at "/usr/bin/python3.4" to "/usr/bin/python2.7".

Other thing is "mintMenu" the advanced start menu in the panel is now working again.

Comment: Sounds like you screwed your system python or have changed your system default

Comment: Are you using python 2 or python 3? Like Padraic said, you've somehow broken your system python install, perhaps by installing the wrong version of distribute or some confusion in 2 vs. 3. It might be pretty difficult to recover at this point. Can you reinstall your OS? If not I would try reinstalling your OS's python package. Another option would be to create a new python install (e.g. from source). In the future, try to install everything in a `virtualenv` (python2) or `pyvenv` (python3), that way it's impossible to break your system python.

Comment: i am currently using python 3 i did change the symbolic link "python" in /usr/bin to point to python3 from python2.

Comment: @RuthraKumar,  well that is  not a good idea, remove the symlink. Python3 is not backwards compatible with python2. Unless you know exactly what you are doing don't mess with your systems default python

Comment: Thanks @PadraicCunningham it worked, changed the symbolic to point /usr/bin/python2.7 and now "pip install beautifulsoup4" works and also when entering a wrong command in terminal shows the usual "No command found" message

Comment: @RuthraKumar, no worries,  be careful with your system python, once you do mess it up it is usually a case of having to reinstall the OS.

Comment: dpkg -S pythonX.X  >log.txt //Check which dir or library is missed !

Comment: @RuthraKumar You should probably delete the question or you can answer it yourself explaining the problem if you think that will help others.

Comment: what is the coammnd to remove just the python3.4?